# Handle a HTTPS WebSocket handshake in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, https, websocket

I have a local c# server running and listening on localhost and a browser connecting to a cloud service running a JavaScript HTML5 implementation of websockets. Standard `ws://`

This works great over `HTTP://` and I can read the header and use it, but I need it to run in `HTTPS://` I understand that I have to change to `wss://` and this does connect to my server but the header is garbled/encrypted. 
I have looked into `SslStream` but drawn a blank.

How do I handle this WebSocket Secure header in C#?

Comment: If your app is behind a Proxy load balancer, it would normally manage the SSL for you (accessing your app without encryption). If you need to manage SSL, complete the SSL handshake first (usually right after you `accept` the connection) and than parse protocol specific data (HTTP, Websockets, SMTP etc').

Comment: I have managed to get the ssl handshake completed and parsed the http header handshake for the websocket but i cannot keep the connection open for data transfer..

Comment: Can you explain how you manage to get SSL handshake because i have same problem, i am also getting blank SslStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments:

If your app is behind a Proxy load balancer, it would normally manage the SSL for you (accessing your app without encryption).

If you need to manage SSL, complete the SSL handshake first (usually right after you accept the connection) and than parse protocol specific data (HTTP, Websockets, SMTP etc').